# Validate first 2 characters of a textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a textbox whereby the user needs to input his/her mobile number.  However I need to validate the first 2 numbers (characters) to make sure that the mobile number is in the correct format (as one of the validation rules).

The mobile number needs to start with any of the following 2 digits:

44xxxxxx
55xxxxxx
65xxxxxx
78xxxxxx

Can anyone tell me how it's possible to validate the first two characters number and check that they are either one of the options mentioned above?

**EDIT**
This is what I had tried but it did not work:

HTML

```
<input id="mob" name="mob" type="tel" placeholder="Enter your mobile number">
<a href="#" id="validate">Validate</a>
```

​
JS

```
var mobile_prefix = $('#mob').subsubstr(0,2);
$('#validate').click(function(){
if (mobile_prefix == 44||55||65||78) {
alert('correct');
}
else {
    alert('incorrect');
}
});
```

​

Comment: You can use either a regular expression or just check if the string starts with any of the valid digits

Comment: There are many ways to do this.  Are you allowed to use 3rd party libraries, or do you need to hand-craft the soln?

Comment: @jharig23: 3rd party libraries?? Keep it simple, you don't need anything else other than what the javascript language already has.

Comment: `jQuery('#txt').text().substr(0,2)`

Comment: You can't abbreviate conditions like that. You have to write `if( mobile_prefix == 44 || mobile_prefix == 55 || mobile_prefix == 66 ` and so on.

Comment: @RuiJarimba: I should have said jQuery plugins.  Yes, I agree that keeping it simple is good.  However, if the project requires some fancy-shmancy UI decorations, plugins give you the ability for free.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think [.match()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) has what you're looking for. Just brush up on some [regular expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

```
if (StringFromSelectField.match(/^(44|55|65|78)/)) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: This works... I was in the middle of testing the same thing when you posted :) I added the "End Anchor" just in case the author wanted to also test for length, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use `substring` from javascript

```
var FirstTwoLetters = TextFromYourInput.substring(0,2);
```

and then you can compare first two letters with your pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Using a regular expression would probably be the easiest:

```
({phone number}).match(/^(44|55|65|78).*$/)
```

Answer (score 0):

So first variable for input filed;Kind of my way;)
first check if that input is not empty and has 3 or more signs.
On the end is variable which I use on the end to allow form.submit().
If you want you can add before each getting val() `$.trim(postcode.val()) != ''`

```
var postcode = $('#post_code');
        if(postcode.val() != '' && postcode.val().length > 2){
            var shortPostCode = postcode.val().substring(0,2);
            var validPostCode = /^(EH|KY)/;
            if(!shortPostCode.match(validPostCode)){
                postcode.after('<span class="error">Post code must start with EH</span>');
                dataValid = false;
            }
        }
```